# bgm player without being refreshed

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

it has come across in my mind that installing BGM music player is fashionable. so im triyng to install this kind of music player on my website.

http://cyberagent.github.io/boombox.js/demo/single.html

but the problem is that i can't refresh or move on to the other page while the music is playing, because otherwise the music will be cut off.

so the idea behind this is basically, loading the whole html content of the hyperlink using ajax and replace the current content as html with new contents.

I thought of something like this

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); $.ajax(this.href) });

or using jquery.load in order to achieve this, but then my knowledge of current webtechnology doesn't stretch far beyond.

and i wonder how the soundcloud has managed to make this work.

and i also wonder if the idea above is achievable how i should deal with the address change. does it keep up with the new url of the hyperlink?

or, im trying to go for frameset, so that the music player stays on top of the page without being refreshed, but i want to know if it's possible to make the music go on but the player stays in the other frameset so that way i can control the music.

http://codepen.io/dpeukert/pen/OVZLjo

check this out for music player im trying to install on frameset.

and here is the html.

```
    <audio src="http://gazze.com/demo/Isthislove.mp3"></audio>
<div id="bg">
<div id="original-link">Show the original picture</div>
<div id="load-song">
    <div id="load-song-url">Load a song from an URL</div>
    <div id="load-song-file">Load a song from a file</div>
</div>
<div id="tested">Tested and working in Chrome 43, FF 39, Opera 30, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge.</div>
<div id="credits">
    Made by <a href="http://www.danielpeukert.cz/">Daniel Peukert</a>     for the <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/DevWars/comments/3ch8uw/devwars_weekly_update_07_jul_2015/">DevWars weekly challenge</a><br>
        <a href="https://dribbble.com/shots/2133799-Is-This-Love-Music-Player">Original Dribble</a> by <a href="http://www.loopim.com/">Amit Keren</a>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="file" accept="audio/*">
<div id="original"></div>
<div id="player">
<div id="albumart"></div>
  <div id="volume">
    <div id="plus">+</div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.01">
    <div id="minus">–</div>
  </div>
  <progress max="100" value="0"></progress>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.5" id="seek">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="times">
      <div id="current">0:00</div>
      <div id="total">0:00</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
      <div id="playpause" title="Play/Pause (Space)"></div>
      <div id="trackinfo">
        <div id="track" title="Is This Love">Is This Love</div>
        <div id="artist" title="Bob Marley">Bob Marley</div>
      </div>
      <div id="buttons">
        <div id="repeat" title="Repeat (R)"></div>
        <div id="rewind" title="Rewind - 10 seconds (←)"></div>
        <div id="forward" title="Forward - 10 seconds (→)"></div>
      </div> <!-- #buttons -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div> <!-- #controls -->
  </div> <!-- #main -->
</div> <!-- #player -->
<div class="shadow"></div>
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

and if there's any other idea as to how i can achieve this, please let me know. help will be greatly appreciated.